# Microsoft SQL Data Sync Agent Preview Register failed

Tags: synchronization, azure-sql-database

I'm tring to use SQL Data Sync agent to synchronize my local database with my database on azure.

Now I am having a problem that I cannot register my localdb in the agent.
[image]

I have a database in my local db named "suncoreDB" as filled in the picture.

When I test connection , some errors occurs:
[image]
[image]

Please help me out. Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Questions:
1. Is the suncoreDB on the same machine as where you installed the client agent?
2. What SQL Server version is suncoreDB?
3. When you access suncoreDB using SSMS, do you use Windows or SQL authentication?